# Python 3: destroy tkinter window after calling lambda function, without quitting the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So, I want to close the Tkinter window when

```
w = Button(root, text="Tryck här för att skriva till high score lista", command=lambda :high_score(attempts, computer_word_list_for_display))   
w.pack(fill=X)
```

is pressed.

I have tried

```
w = Button(root, text="Tryck här för att skriva till high score lista", command=lambda :high_score(attempts, computer_word_list_for_display), root.destroy())    
w.pack(fill=X)
```

but it only gives me an error message. Any ideas?

Here is the function as a whole...

```
def render_game_after(attempts,computer_word_list_for_display):
    root = Tk()

    w = Label(root, text="Detta är spelmenyn. Här kommer några alternativ.", bg = "black",fg = "white")
    w.pack(fill=X)

    w = Button(root, text="Tryck här för att skriva till high score lista", command=lambda :high_score(attempts, computer_word_list_for_display))
    w.pack(fill=X)

    w = Button(root, text="Klicka här för att se ditt resultat i ett annat fönster",command= lambda:render_highscore(attempts, computer_word_list_for_display))
    w.pack(fill=X)

    w = Button(root, text="Tryck här för att avsluta spelet", command=lambda: quit())
    w.pack(fill=X)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I fixed the formatting of your code, but please check that it's correct.

Comment: What is the error message that you get?

Answer (score 1):

Better create function ie.

```
def on_quit(a, b):
   high_score(a, b)
   root.destroy()

w = Button(root, text="...", command=lambda:on_quit(attempts, computer_word_list_for_display))
```

It will be more readable.

Comment: Thank you! So, upon pressing the button the functions will be called and the window will close?